# subclass of class with compositeid

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

is the following hbm.xml mapping possible in MappingByCode?

```
<joined-subclass>
  <key>
    <column name="keypart1"/>
    <column name="keypart2"/>
    <column name="keypart3"/>
  </key>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out.

```
class JoinedSubclassMapping : JoinedSubclassMapping<Subclass>
{
    public JoinedSubclassMapping()
    {
        Key(key =>
        {
            key.Columns(c => c.Name("keypart1"), c => c.Name("keypart2"), c => c.Name("keypart3"));
        });
    }
}
```